# Transparent objects block objects behind them when not selected

Tags: materials, 3d-view, transparency

In renders this the transparency works ok. But **in viewport in materials view** something is very broken. When I selected the transparent object the object behind it shows up ok. When I select nothing the transparent object becomes solid and blocks the other one. When I select the object behind the transparent object it stays blocked behind the transparent object.

Blend file added. When you open the file just click the different objects and see how the transparency turns on and off depending what is selected on both separate transparent objects. Render is fine but I can't work in render view.

blend: https://www108.zippyshare.com/v/gWH4KN9d/file.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the properties of the "glass" shader, under Settings / Viewport color, lower the Alpha value.

In the properties of every transparent object, in Object / Display, check Transparency.

Bonus : this kind of transparency also works in Solid view, not only in Material view.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to have worked. So many places to check. Is there any way to keep the selection edge for transparent objects? When I select transparent the selected edge goes away so it is impossible to tell when a transparent object is selected or not?

Comment: Enabling "Wire" (in the same tab) seems to solve that, I don't know if there is a better way.